# Date filters require jquery and daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

So i'm following up with this [How to use Vue-tables-2 — tables for vuejs](https://medium.com/@lopezquekk/how-to-use-vue-tables-2-tables-for-vuejs-c56b7823c9c2)
i did everything he did, but i still get this error:

Date filters require jquery and daterangepicker

heres my app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import VueI18Next from '@panter/vue-i18next';
import {ClientTable, Event} from 'vue-tables-2';
import daterangepicker from 'daterangepicker';
window.moment = require('moment');
import './vendor.js'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import i18next from './i18n.js';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(VueI18Next);
Vue.use(ClientTable);


new Vue({
   i18n,
   router,
   render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

and i also tried use Vue.use('daterangepicker') the page wont open and i get this in console

[Vue warn]: Vue is a constructor and should be called with the `new` keyword
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on string '.prev'
Uncaught TypeError: this._init is not a function

my component

```
data() {
        return {
            tableData: [],
            columns: ['orderID','client','date', 'status','total', 'action'],
            options: {
                filterByColumn: true,
                dateColumns:['date'],
                dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                datepickerOptions: {
                    showDropdowns: true,
                    autoUpdateInput: true,
                },
                sortIcon: {
                    is: 'fa-sort',
                    base: 'fas',
                    up: 'fa-sort-up',
                    down: 'fa-sort-down'
                },
                headings: {
                    orderID: 'ID',
                    client: 'Client Name',
                    date: 'Purchase Date',
                    status: 'Order Status',
                    total: 'Total',
                    action: 'Action'

                },
                sortable: ['client', 'date','status','total'],
                filterable: ['client', 'date', 'total'],
                perPage:10,
                perPageValues:[10],
                requestAdapter(data) {
                    return {
                        page: data.page ?  data.page : 1,
                    }
                },
                responseAdapter({data}) {
                    return {
                        data : data.data,
                        count: data.count
                    }
                },

            }
        }
    },
```